# MYSQL search multiple condition in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, where-clause

```
table1
-------------------------------
| id | color     | shape      |
|------------------------------
|  1 | green     | triangle   |
|  2 | green     | square     |
|  3 | blue      | rectangle  |
|  4 | white     | sphere     |
|  5 | yellow    | triangle   |
-------------------------------
```

I want to get a result where row has multiple condition focusing in one column.
Here is my code.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE shape = 'triangle' and shape = 'square';
```

However, result should have the same value in column color.
Is it possible to have a result as below?

```
-------------------------------
| id | color     | shape      |
|------------------------------
|  1 | green     | triangle   |
|  2 | green     | square     |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: `WHERE shape = 'triangle' and shape = 'square'` - you can't have different values in same row at same time. You probably meant `or` instead of `and`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    shape in ('triangle', 'square')
    and exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.shape in ('triangle, 'square')
            and t1.color = t.color
            and t1.shape <> t.shape
    )
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also use window functions. Assuming that there are no duplicates in `(color, shape)` tuples:

```
select id, color, shape
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by color) cnt
    from mytable t
    where shape in ('triangle', 'square')
) t
where cnt > 1
```